Changing asg when using eks managed nodegroup
Are we supposed to make manual changes to the asg if we created it as an eks managed nodepool?
For example, I can set the desired count in the asg but it won't match the desired count in the eks managed pool. Which makes me wonder why I can even do it.
Obviously there are more config options when editing the ASG, but then doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of using EKS managed node group?
If anyone has any good docs on explaining this, that would be great.
